# Sending byte to server

Tags: java

I am sending byte array to the server and server should receive the data I sent. But the server taking very long time to receive the data. Server is waiting in Inputstream.

If I send String data by converting to bytes then the server will receive. I dont know what is happening. Please help me.

Client:

```java
void Send(byte []arr)
{   
    //Other code

    String s=new String(arr);
    byte []msgByte=s.getBytes();
    try
    {
        outStream.write(msgByte);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {}

     //Other Code
}
```

Server:

```java
InputStream inStream1=connection.openInputStream();
BufferedReader bReader1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream1));
String lineRead=bReader1.readLine();
System.out.println(lineRead);
inStream1.close();
```

Comment: did you try closing the outStream?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a '\n' (new line character) at the end of the message because you expect to read a line on the server and also you need to flush the stream after writing the message, because, by default system is not automatically flushing it and also flushing depends on the type of the `OutputStream` used.

```
void Send(byte[] arr) {
    // Other code

    String s = new String(arr) + "\n"; // appending '\n'
    byte[] msgByte = s.getBytes();
    try {
        outStream.write(msgByte);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    outStream.flush(); //flushing the stream
    // Other Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the outStream using `outStream.close()`